# Find in file and then move that file using Linux?

Tags: linux

I want to be able to find files that contain certain strings and the move that list of files to directory X

I can use this command to find the files

```
find . -iname 'commaus*' | xargs grep '>24901<' -sl
```

and this command to move files

```
mv * /home/user/scripts/xslt
```

But is there a way to combine these commands so that the found files are moved.

I have seen similar joined find/action commands such as

```
find /home/user -name property_images -ok rm -f {} \;
```

but following this structure is returning an error

```
find . -iname 'commaus*' | xargs grep '>24901<' -sl -ok mv {} /home/user/scripts/xslt;
```

Comment: belongs to unix.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a loop. In this case, try:

```
for i in `find . -iname 'commaus*' | xargs grep '>24901<' -sl`; do mv "$i" /home/user/scripts/xslt/; done
```

Very hackish, but it should work.

Answer (score 2):

you can do this by wrapping it in a for loop

```
for i in `find /path/to/search -iname 'optionalfilename' -exec grep -H -m1 '>24901<' {} \; | awk -F: '{print $1}'
do
   mv $i /path/to/new/location
done
```

This will not work as expected if filenames contain spaces or colons

Comment: Hey highfive! +1 for Jinx! :)

Comment: if it's not a hack, it's not unix.

Answer (score 2):

Also might be able to try (without loop):

```
find . -iname 'commaus*' | grep '>24901<' -sl -ok | xargs mv -t /home/user/scripts/xslt
```